# When does Gianduia get released?

Tags: html, silverlight, flash

So I'm way behind on this one. Apple is trying to bring another figure into the flash/silverlight game with Gianduia? I know apple was trying to destroy this market but I thought they were truly trying to go a different route such as HTML5.

Well when does this Gianduia come out?

Will it really be able to counter silverlight/flash. Will it really have the speed and smoothness that flash/silverlight can offer with complication?

Isn't the bottom line that something has to compile the script such as a plugin and this is what is really what makes flash/silverlight run like real applications and not slow scripts in browsers?

Comment: It's objective because I'm asking for the release date and if it will actually compete with Flash.

Comment: from what i've read it sounds more like a Dreamweaver killer than a Flash killer (oh snap!) :p... besides, if it requires a Mac to run like all of Apple's other development tools, i really can't imagine this seriously competing with the Flash platform.

Comment: lol, if they kept the wall up on this project that would be silly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a Javascript RIA framework. Apple has [a ton of them](http://rentzsch.tumblr.com/post/286536824/apples-myriad-javascript-frameworks), and there are even more outside Apple (with [Cappuccino](http://cappuccino.org/) being most prominent). Apple showed off the framework at a developer conference once, and a couple of news sites somehow heard about it much later when the whole Apple vs. Flash thing was in full swing, and those sites wrote it up with the angle "Apple is developing a Flash killer!"

Ajaxian [provided a little sanity](http://ajaxian.com/archives/gianduia) on the subject back when the story was newer (I hesitate to say "new," since the sites were reporting on a *year-old conference talk*).